# How to create a scrollable photo stream for mobile app

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am new new jQuery and mobile web app development, and I want to learn.

Kindly guide me: how can I create a scrollable photo stream; that is, when I swap a picture with my finger, it shows a new picture. In other words, I can move pictures backward & forward with my finger.

Answer (score 0):

I not entirely sure but here are a few resources to help you out. First and foremost is jquery mobile. [an example of gridding in jquery, check the last example](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-grids.html)

You can use jquery mobile to do most anything you want!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.photoswipe.com/. If you really want to make one yourself there are hundreds of tutorials out there.

1. http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/
2. http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/02/jquery-image-slider-plugins.html

Since you want it to be with touch events you would just bind to swipeleft and swiperight instead of click.

Comment: can i do it this way, the images fetch from database & will show in images unordered list, then when user click on particular image i get its primary key id which is in data base, i am using asp.net, but the onClick & onSelectedIndex event is not raised, i don't know whats the problem with this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to open a separate question for that. I don't use asp.net.